# Adding a image to an element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a element that is randomly appearing on the screen using javascript. What would I do in order to add an image using javascript to the randomly generated  element?

```js
function addEnemy() {
  var interval = 0.1;
  if (iterations > 1500) {
    interval = 5;
  } else if (iterations > 1000) {
    interval = 3;
  } else if (iterations > 500) {
    interval = 1;
  }

  if (getRandom(50) == 0) {
    var elementName = "enemy" + getRandom(10000000);
    var enemy = createSprite(elementName, getRandom(450), -40, 45, 45);
    var enemiesDiv = document.getElementById("enemiesDiv");
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.id = enemy.element;
    element.className = "enemy";
    enemiesDiv.appendChild(element);
    enemies[enemies.length] = enemy;
    element.enemy.innerHTML
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `img` element, give it the source to your image, then append that img element to your `element` you created. (I would suggest using a more descriptive variable name than just "element")

The relevant code could look like this:

```
var myImage = document.createElement('img');
myImage.src = 'my_image.jpg';
element.appendChild(myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit too broad, but I think you could consider using the background property of your created div. Something like this:

```js
function addEnemy() {
  var interval = 0.1;
  if (iterations > 1500) {
    interval = 5;
  } else if (iterations > 1000) {
    interval = 3;
  } else if (iterations > 500) {
    interval = 1;
  }

  if (getRandom(50) == 0) {
    var elementName = "enemy" + getRandom(10000000);
    var enemy = createSprite(elementName, getRandom(450), -40, 45, 45);
    var enemiesDiv = document.getElementById("enemiesDiv");
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.id = enemy.element;
    element.className = "enemy";

    // Here
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_enemy.png')";

    enemiesDiv.appendChild(element);
    enemies[enemies.length] = enemy;
    element.enemy.innerHTML
  }
}
```